# How to avoid double jQuery object lookups

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a jQuery hover code snippet that will add markup on hover and then work with the class. Here is the JS.

```
$('.port-item').hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $($this.find("img")).attr('title');
        $this.append('<div class="port-item-cover"><h3>' + name + '</h3><div>');
        $($this.children(".port-item-cover")).fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        $($(this).children(".port-item-cover")).fadeOut();
});
```

The HTML markup is pretty simple:

```
<div class="port-item">
   <a href="/portfolio/#/<?=$p['shortname']?>">
      <img src="images/portfolio/p_<?=$p['shortname']?>0.jpg" title="<?=$p['title']?>">
   </a>
</div>
```

Two Questions: the main one is, how do I avoid the double lookups in jquery `$($(this).children("#element"))` to look up the child elements inside the current scope? It's pretty ugly in the second function, is there a better way?

The second question is what is the best way to check if this has been previously hovered over before and if the markup is there so I do not add it on subsequent hovers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is easy. You dont need the outer `$` call. `.find()` will already return a jQuery object. Just write it like this

```
$(this).children("#element")
```

As for detecting if it has been hovered over previously, you would have to set a flag somewhere. That might look like this:

```
var hoveredOver = false;
$('.port-item').hover(function(){
    hoveredOver = true;
    //continue event handler
}
```

You may need to get fancy with that depending on your specific circumstance. Perhaps setting the flag using `.data()` would be better if you are hovering over a lot of things.

```
$('.port-item').hover(function(){
    $(this).data('hoveredOver', true);
    //continue event handler
}
```

**EDIT** Missed a question there. Third answer: to tell if the DOM object (markup) is there already you search for it and check the length like so:

```
if($(this).find('#port-item-cover').length>0)
{
    //element exists
}
else
{
    //element does not exist, add it
}
```

Comment: Ok. I was over-thinking the look-up on the children. haha! Thanks everyone!  I didn't know about $(this).data(...) - I will have to look into that.

Comment: $(this).data(...) is useful if you want to add attributes to a certain element without actually creating a custom HTML attribute on the element itself.  I use it for flags, much like what @Jeff used it for.

Answer (score 1):

1. All jQuery traversal methods already return jQuery objects; you never need to write `$($this.children())`.
2. No.

   a. Mouseleave should never fire without mouseenter.

   b. If there aren't any matching elements, nothing will happen; you won't get an error.

However, you need to remove the element after the animation finishes; right now, you're adding a separate element on every hover.

Note that you simplify your `mouseenter` to

```
$('<div class="port-item-cover"><h3>' + name + '</h3><div>')
    .appendTo(this)
    .fadeIn();
```

Comment: That is a much better way to write the `mouseenter` because it controls the scope so nicely. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, use this instead:

```
$(this).children("#element")
```